# Custom view using code or IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder

Is there a right/wrong approach for creating a Custom view using code or IB? I mean what should be the preferred way of designing a custom view.

Comment: Great question, I can't seem to find consensus on this, either and neither can any of the pro iPhone guys I work with. Apple seems to think IB is the way to go, but I feel more productive in code. Code samples on the net go either way...

Comment: Chris, I think there is no concensus because there is no one 'correct' answer. The choice depends what you're trying to achieve in your app and situation.

Comment: Does the answer lie in what one is trying to achieve, in terms of what one's requirement is. Also is it right to think that from a reuse perspective, code is a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for all broad questions, the answer is "It depends what you're trying to do". Both IB and writing code have their merits. Some projects will end up with a bit of both.

There's some discussion here:

http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/03/striking-the-balance-interface-builder-vs-code/

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I started out working with IB. But as I went deeper into iOS development, I started building my views in code....

Gave me a higher sense of control over my view objects.

But, like everyone else says, both ways are correct; It just depends on what you're comfortable with.

Like me, try both and see which one works best for you. You have nothing to lose either way.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do it in code but now I mostly use IB to lay out my views and then do fine tuning in code, like setting the font for a UITextView. Always seems odd that you can't do that one in IB...